# How to save a web sqlite database to a file?

Tags: android, html, file, google-chrome, web-sql

I am working with web SQL in Chrome, and I need to get the file. The only way I can get the file is in the databases folder, which would work, however I need my site to work with Chrome on Android, and its databases folder is on its emulated storage, which the user can't access. Is there some way to get the web database to a different spot (or at least be able to convert it to data URL or something)?